# Regular expressions in notepad++ (Search and Replace)

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++

I have a list of thousands of records within a .txt document.
some of them look like these records

```
201910031044         "00059"    "11.31AG"  "Senior Champion"
201910031044         "00060"    "GBA146"  "Junior Champion"
201910031044         "00999"    "10.12G"  "ProAM"
201910031044         "00362"    "113.1LI"  "Abcd"
```

Whenever a record similar to this occurs I'd like to get rid of the last words/numbers/etc in the last quotation marks (like "Senior Champion", "Junior Champion" etc. There are many possibilities here)

e.g. (before)

```
201910031044         "00059"    "11.31AG"  "Senior Champion"
```

after

```
201910031044         "00059"    "11.31AG"
```

I tried the following regex but it wouldn't work.

Search: `^([0-9]{17,17} + "[0-9]{8,8}" + "[a-zA-Z0-9]").*$`

Replace: `\1` (replace string)

OK I forgot the `.` (dot) sign however even if I do not have a `.` (dot) sign it would not work. Not sure if it has anything to do when using the `+` sign used more than once.

Comment: The logic behind why the "Senior Champion" line gets altered is not clear to me.  At first glance I would say that regex alone is not sufficient to handle your requirement; you'll have to parse this file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'd like to get rid of the last words/numbers/etc in the last quotation marks

This does the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+\K\h+".*?"$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  .+        # 1 or more any character but newline
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  ".*?"     # something inside quotes
$           # end of line
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: thanks. this works perfectly. also found a problem when tab stops in between but this solution does not have any issues with them!

Comment: @Elch007: That what `\h` is for. It matches horizontal space (i.e. space or tabulation, `[ \t]`)

Answer (score 0):

The RegEx looks for the 4th double quote:

```
^(?:[^"]*\"){4}([^|]*)
```

You can see this demo: https://regex101.com/r/wJ9yS6/163

You will still need to parse the lines, so probably easier opening in excel or parsing using code as a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the count of your characters:

- you specify that the line should start with *exactly* 17 digits (`[0-9]{17,17}`). However, there are only 12 digits in the data `201910031044`.

  - you can specify exactly 12 digits by using `{12}` or if it could be 12-17, then `{12,17}`. I'll assume exactly 12 based on the current data.
- similarly, for the second column you specify that it's *exactly* 8 digits surrounded by quotes (`"[0-9]{8,8}"`) but it only has 5 digits surrounded by quotes.

  - again, you can specify exactly 5 with `{5}` or 5-8 with `{5,8}`. I will assume exactly 5.
- finally, there is no quantifier for the final field, so the regex tries to match *exactly* one character that is a letter or a number surrounded by quotes `"[a-zA-Z0-9]"`.

  - I'm not sure if there is any limit on the number of characters, so I would go with one or more using `+` as quantifier `"[a-zA-Z0-9]+"` - if you can have zero or more, then you can use `*`, or if it's any other count from **m** to **n**, then you can use `{m,n}` as before.

Not a character count problem but the final column can also have dots but the regex doesn't account for. You can just add `.` inside the square brackets and it will *only* match dot characters. It's usually used as a wildcard but it loses its special meaning inside a character class (`[]`), so you get `"[a-zA-Z0-9.]+"`

Putting it all together, you get

Search: `^([0-9]{12} + "[0-9]{5}" + "[a-zA-Z0-9.]+").*$`
Replace: `\1`

Which will get rid of anything after the third field in Notepad++.

This can be shortened a bit by using `\d` instead of `[0-9]` for digits and `\s+` for whitespace instead of `+`. As a benefit, `\s` will also match other whitespace like tabs, so you don't have to manually account for those. This leads to

Search: `^(\d{12}\s+"\d{5}"\s+"[a-zA-Z0-9.]+").*$`
Replace: `\1`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the last words/numbers/etc in the last quotation marks you  could capture in a group what is before that and match the last quotation marks and everything between it to remove it using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

If what is between the values can be spaces or tabs, you could use `[ \t]+` to match those (using `\s` could also match a newline)

Note that `{17,17}` and `{8,8}` may also be written as `{17}` and `{8}` which in this case should be `{12}` and `{5}`

```
^([0-9]{12}[ \t]+"[0-9]{5}"[ \t]+"[a-zA-Z0-9.]+")[ \t]{2,}"[^"\r\n]+"
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[0-9]{12}[ \t]+` Match 12 digits and 1+ spaces or tabs
  - `"[0-9]{5}"[ \t]+` Match 5 digits between `"` and 1+ spaces or tabs
  - `"[a-zA-Z0-9.]+"` Match 1+ times any of the listed between `"`
- `)` Close group
- `[ \t]{2,}` Match 1+ times
- `"[^"\r\n]+"`

In the replacement use group 1 `$1`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zxY6Jz/1)

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: thanks for this solution as well. also handles the tab stops well. was my mistake for putting the wrong numbers (17 and 8)!